# How can I apply a ripple effect on the screen/camera (not on puddles or rivers)

Tags: animation

I want to find a way to do this. And all I found was about rivers and other stuff. I've recently played sonic generations and every time I boost/speed up there's a ripple effect on the screen I want to do a similar thing in my animations. Any suggestions ??

Comment: I find very nice solution in less than 20second of googling. :-) https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?332904-Ripple-effect-for-animations

Comment: all you need is make image sequence of water rings

Comment: can you add a link where we can see the effect you are after?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use *dynamic paint* to obtain many ripple effects in a more flexible way than using the compositor uniquely :

[image]

The usage may be different from the one you could obtain with the compositor, but this approach can interest you.

Here is the settings :

- A plane, with a subsurface modifier (set to 'simple' in order to keep it angular)
- And a dynamic paint modifier

[image]

- In the physics panel of the plane, set the dynamic paint to canvas, then to wave and eventually adjust the parameters :

[image]

- Make another mesh (or several, here I used a sphere) and add it also a dynamic paint modifier, but this time set it to brush :

[image]

And you are done : simply move the brush object into the canvas surface and it makes ripples during the animation (you need to run the animation to obtain it).

You can mix it with your animation, using for instance a glass shader, or putting it in another layer and merge it with the compositor.

[image]